# How to retrieve latest id from a database table in Adonis.js?

Tags: mysql, database, adonis.js

I wanted to know if I can retrieve the latest id from a database table?

For example, I have a `User` table and I want to retrieve the latest `id` in the `User` table. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Show us some code examples. .. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you id field auto increments then you can MAX(id) to get the last inserted id, for your scenario, MAX(id) is the best solve.

Comment: I would suggest to use `getMax('id')` if anyone wanted to retrieve a single variable because `max('id')` returns an array of the max value. Source: [Documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/query-builder)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for the **last()** or for **pickInverse** Model method, depends on your version.

```
yield User.query().last() // 3.2
await User.pickInverse() // > 4.0
```

Comment: I've tried this and display the data in console log, the value I get using `pickInverse()` is:

`VanillaSerializer {
  rows:
   [ Election {
       __setters__: [Array],
       '$attributes': [Object],
       '$persisted': true,
       '$originalAttributes': [Object],
       '$relations': {},
       '$sideLoaded': {},
       '$parent': null,
       '$frozen': false,
       '$visible': undefined,
       '$hidden': undefined } ],
  pages: null,
  isOne: false }`

What does this means? How can I get the id?

Comment: Try this `(await User.query().last()).id`, **last()** method is not documented on 4.1, but i tried and it works

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if this is what you looking for as i never used this Adonis.js but i hope this helps:

```
* createRole () {
  role = new Role();
  role.name = "New Role";
  yield role.save();
  console.log(role);
  return role;
}
```

Variable `role` after `yield role.save()` will contain the last inserted id and other associated properties.

Source: https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/issues/241

Comment: I already tried this one before you suggest it to me. Apparently this applies for right after when you newly insert a row. In my case, I just want to retrieve the latest id from a table.

Comment: @quratulhzm Oh cool! As i told i was not sure if that is what you are looking for! Just tried to help and maybe my answer will help someone in future ;) And i m glad you found solution!

Answer (score 0):

Return the data in `desc` then get the first element with `.first()`.
example: .

`Release.query().orderBy('id', 'desc').first()`